# Async/Await Function keeps triggering re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I having problem trying to get data from backend using axios. The function returns a Promise and whenever I call the function my component keeps rendering non-stop. Here is the code.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

const DashBoard = () => {
  const [student, setStudent] = useState<{ [key: string]: string }[]>([]);
  const studentId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("studentId") as string);
  const examResult: { [key: string]: string }[] = JSON.parse(
    localStorage.getItem("englishAnswers") as string
  );

  const getStudent = async () => {
    const { data } = await Axios.get(
      `http://localhost:3500/students/${studentId}`
    );
    setStudent(data);
  };
  getStudent(); //this line here keeps triggering re-render non stop;
```

Comment: You shouldn't initiate HTTP network requests during the render phase (unless you are doing it in a server component). Learn more about [API requests in reactJs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getStudent` is being invoked on every render:

```
getStudent();
```

Since the operation within that function updates state, it triggers a re-render.  So every render triggers a re-render, indefinitely.

If the intent is only to execute this *on the first render*, wrap it in a `useEffect` with an empty dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getStudent();
}, []);
```

If `studentId` might change and you want to re-invoke this if it does, add that to the dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getStudent();
}, [studentId]);
```

You might take it a step further and put the function itself into a `useCallback`:

```
const getStudent = useCallback(async () => {
  const { data } = await Axios.get(
    `http://localhost:3500/students/${studentId}`
  );
  setStudent(data);
}, [studentId]);
```

This will only create a new instance of the function if/when `studentId` changes.  Then the function itself can be the dependency for executing it:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getStudent();
}, [getStudent]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your `getStudent()` call in an `useEffect` hook. Because currently you are calling the `getStudent` function on **each** render, and as it triggers a `setState` method this leads into an infinite rendering.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getStudent = async () => {
    const { data } = await Axios.get(
      `http://localhost:3500/students/${studentId}`
    );
    setStudent(data);
  };

  getStudent();
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you guys. It worked. But when I `console.log` the data set by the `setStudent`, it renders twice. That is four times including the react_devtools_backend.js render. Why is that?

Comment: That is a normal behavior in development mode. You can check this article that will give you clear insights about what is going on: https://blog.bitsrc.io/react-v18-0-useeffect-bug-why-do-effects-run-twice-39babecede93